# PrimeNG Babylon theme

Tags: angular, themes, primeng

Angular 8 and Babylon theme: it has some odd and annoying blue borders with `p-tree-component`.

I don't find in CSS/SCSS files where it comes and how to get rid of these; at least change to less annoying.

Has anyone an idea how to customize this, thanks.

[image]

Comment: in styles.scss (or styles.css) add `*:focus { outline: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments if you do `*:focus {outline: none;}` in `styles.css`, it will apply to each and every element in DOM. Due to this some other thing might break.

You can use `::ng-deep` pseudo selector for this, in your component css where `p-tree` is used,

```css
p-tree::ng-deep .ui-treenode-content:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

This ensures that changes will happen only in `p-tree` and not in whole application.

Comment: OK, tried that, and it does the trick correctly. And of course is much better; although both ways are correct in *my case*. Thank you, I totally forgot that ```ng-deep``` possibility. That might help in some other problem too!